# how to set the radiobutton value and get the selected value in spring mvc

Tags: java, radio-button

I am creating a quiz app and it contains four options when the user    clicked the option it is not being recorded

```
<ul>
    <c:forEach var="question" items="${questions}">
        <h2 class="qestion">${question.quesDescription}</h2>
        <li>
            <input type="hidden" name="questionId" value="${question.quesId}"/><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="question_${question.quesId}" value="${question.option1}"/>
            <input type="radio" name="question_${question.quesId}" value="${question.option2}"/>${question.option2}<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="question_${question.quesId}" value="${question.option3}"/>${question.option3}<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="question_${question.quesId}" value="${question.option4}"/>${question.option4}<br/>
        </li>
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

---

```
@GetMapping("/getResult")
public ModelAndView getResult(HttpServletRequest req) {
    int stdid = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("studentId"));
    int subid = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("subjectId"));

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    String[] questionIds = req.getParameterValues("questionId");
    double result=0.0;

        for (String questionId : questionIds) {
            int quesid = Integer.parseInt(questionId);
            Questions q = quesrepo.getQuestionsById(quesid);
            String selectedOption = req.getParameter("question_" + questionId);
            String correctOption = q.getCorrectOption();

            if (selectedOption == null) {
                selectedOption = "";
            }

            if (selectedOption.equals(correctOption)) {
                result += 1.0;
            } else {
                result -= 0.25;
            }
        }

    Results res = new Results();
    res.setStdId(stdid);
    res.setSubId(subid);
    res.setScore(result);
    resrepo.save(res);
    mv.addObject("result", result);
    mv.setViewName("results");
    return mv;  
}
```

How to get the selected option? I am unable to get the option selected by user!!

Comment: Please reformat your code

Comment: please reformat the code.  or  try by putting some println in the controller and alerts in the html or jsp whatever you are using

Comment: I should start a GoFundMe for the time I spent formatting this. Good grief!!